# asp net identity - login won't authenticate correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net web forms, coding in VB and suddenly my identity login/reg stopped working. When I'm logging in, it doesn't authenticate that it is logged in, same with registration. I have connection with the sql.

Login.aspx

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="LoginStatus" Visible="false">
        <p>
           <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="StatusText" /> 
        </p>
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
               <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="LoginForm" Visible="false">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">User name</asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" /> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" /> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Log in" OnClick="SignIn" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                   </asp:PlaceHolder>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="LogoutButton" Visible="false">
        <div>
           <div>
              <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="SignOut" Text="Log out" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
           </div>
        </div>
     </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Login.aspx.vb

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web      
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Owin

Partial Public Class Login
    Inherits Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
                StatusText.Text = String.Format("Logged in as {0}", User.Identity.GetUserName())
                LoginStatus.Visible = True
                LogoutButton.Visible = True
            Else
                LoginForm.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub SignIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)()
        Dim userManager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(userStore)
        Dim user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text)

        If user IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication
            Dim userIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)

            authenticationManager.SignIn(New AuthenticationProperties() With {
                .IsPersistent = False
            }, userIdentity)
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
        Else
            StatusText.Text = "Invalid username or password."
            LoginStatus.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub SignOut(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication
        authenticationManager.SignOut()
        Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx")
    End Sub


End Class
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide the error message that you are getting

Comment: Thats the thing, I'm not getting an error, it justs runs through authenticationManager.SignIn and returns null, then redirects

Comment: I am not sure what is causing this, But you can try this.(C#)  `if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
            {
               // use already logged in
            }
            else
            {
                 var user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text)
                 //rest of your stuff
            }
        `

Comment: Yeah, I got that on pageload/index, but it returns null, that it isnt authenticated:/

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Protected Sub SignIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)()
    Dim userManager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(userStore)
    Dim user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text)

    If user IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication
        Dim userIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)

        authenticationManager.SignIn(New AuthenticationProperties() With {
            .IsPersistent = False
        }, userIdentity)
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
    Else
        StatusText.Text = "Invalid username or password."
        LoginStatus.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I'd suggest you debug the code in the `SignIn` method. A couple of things might be worth checking.

1. Put a break point on this line `Dim user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text)` and see what value it'd return.
2. Check if the line `LoginStatus.Visible = True` is in the right place. To me, perhaps it should have been placed outside of your `If...Else...End If` block. Otherwise it'd not show any UI after the redirection to Login.aspx page. Your authentication might be ok but just you can't see any indications on the UI.
3. Check your web.config settings, particularly in the [authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e(v=vs.85).aspx) configuration section.